# What is the meaning of "Tops in pops"?

Tags: meaning

We have a shop called, "tops in pops", and I would like to know what it means.

I tried Googling it and didn't reach results.

This is [the shop](https://www.facebook.com/topsinpops). We sell groceries

I simply would like to know what this means. "tops in pops" – what does it mean?

Comment: What does this shop sell?

Comment: Also, where is it located?

Comment: We could come up with a lot of fun guesses - I'm picturing spinning tops embedded in giant lollipops myself - but agree that we need more info about the shop to come up with an educated guess.

Comment: I would guess this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top_of_the_Pops, or this: http://www.amazon.com/Tops-Pops-Favorites-Arranged-Instruments/dp/0769230784, or this: https://www.facebook.com/pages/TOPS-in-POPS-LTD/282333775218450.

Comment: I am really not sure if this really mean anything. Sometimes names are meant nothing, they are given some name only for sounding good. For example the name of the band is *Guns and Roses*, they really don't mean anything.

Comment: op here, the shop is this one https://www.facebook.com/topsinpops mostly they sell groceries, like fruits, vegetables, candy, cakes, many other food items. like canned food, crisps the usual

Comment: Perhaps they got their start selling soda pop? Best thing would be to ask the other workers or owner, as "pops" could mean carbonated beverages, popular items, or perhaps other things in local dialect.

Comment: I think this may be off-topic because it is asking about the origin of a business name, and is not about learning English.

Comment: "Tops" can mean "best in" - that might have something to do with it. And if you would like this question to be reopened, please **edit** the question (don't just bury your clarifications down here in the comments).

Comment: I've reopened the question but don't be too frustrated if you don't get a definitiive, clear-cut answer. The store name is a bit confusing to me, so, if there's an English puzzle to be unlocked here, it might be some regional expression.

Answer (score 3):

This shop almost certainly derives its name from the TV program, ‘Top of the Pops’, which ran for more than forty years on the BBC. It puns on the Irish dialect word *pops* or *poppies*, meaning ‘potatoes’ (Kallen, *Irish English*, vol. 2, p. 155). The store, as you say, specializes in fresh produce, and potatoes are traditionally the core of Irish diet. “Tops in Pops” = “the very best potatoes”.

Novelist Hugh Fitzgerald Ryan writes on his [blog](https://hfryan.wordpress.com/tag/top-of-the-pops/) of picking potatoes in his youth:

> After a day of dust and toil, gadflies (*gad=spear*) and stinging nettles, we might be lucky enough to be in time to watch  Alan Freeman in *Six Five Special* or *Top of the Pops*. Alan spoke  somewhat out of the side of his mouth. He was, of course, Australian with the twang of the Antipodes. ‘ Hi there, pop pickers,’  he used to say. He also said ‘Not arf!’  We were pop pickers and we were teenagers, a newly coined word. My mother occasionally referred to potatoes as pops. There was a shop near Mountjoy Square, called *Tops in Pops*. For many years it bore the legend on the window: *now is the hour to get those balls of flour*. This is the highest compliment that can be paid to a spud.

So there you are—all the pieces in one place.

Answer (score 1):

I have a guess.

Small stores are sometimes called *mom and pop* stores (contrasting them to large chain stores, which have several branches across a regional or national area). The expression is meant to highlight how these stores are usually owned by someone in the local community. [WiseGEEK](http://www.wisegeek.org/what-is-a-mom-and-pop-store.htm) mentions that these stores are often owned by the same family for more than one generation.

For example, in the U.S., *Wal-Mart* is a large chain store. So is *Sears.* Those are **not** mom-and-pop stores.

*Tops* is sometimes used as a word meaning "best in".

So, conceivably, *Tops in Pops* could be a clever, rhyming way of saying "One of best mom-and-pop stores you'll find."

The picture on the page you linked to certainly looks like a mom-and-pop store. Nonetheless, I am speculating, and can't claim I know for certain this is true. It could just be a tribute to the shop owner's father (or, as Stoney suggested, maybe they are very proud of their potatoes). Nonetheless, I think this answer might be helpful to an English learner.

[image]